# Status-register : Why it is not working properly

Tags: c, hardware, status-register

A piece of hardware has a one-byte status register. The LSB of the register is a 'busy' bit. The driver must wait for the bit to clear before writing any registers in the device. Consider the following code:

```
char p = remap(MEM_PCI, REG_BASE_ADDRESS, REG_SIZE); 
while (*p & 1);
/ write to hardware */
```

The code doesn't work. Often the driver hangs waiting for the hardware to be "ready". Please list of the reasons for why that could happen.

Comment: should it not start with ``char *p = ...`` ? In your snippet you declare a char not a pointer to a char. Also the keyword ``volatile`` could come in handy.

Comment: Save time: Enable all compiler warnings which should have complained about `while (*p & 1);`

Comment: "*The code doesn't work.*" It doesn't even compile. There's a syntax error and a hard type error in there.

Comment: yes. It would be char *p = remap(MEM_PCI, REG_BASE_ADDRESS, REG_SIZE);